# Test for Python module dependencies being installed

Tags: python, reflection, import, module, python-module

How could one test whether a set of modules is installed, given the names of the modules. E.g.

```
modules = set(["sys", "os", "jinja"])

for module in modules:
  # if test(module exists):
  #   do something
```

While it's possible to write out the tests as:

```
try:
  import sys
except ImportError:
  print "No sys!"
```

This is a bit cumbersome for what I'm doing. Is there a dynamic way to do this?

I've tried eval("import %s"%module) but that complained of a compile error.

I'm grateful for your thoughts and suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`__import__()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html) function like this::

```
for module in modules:
    try:
        __import__(module)
    except ImportError:
        do_something()
```

You can also use [`imp.find_module`](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html) to determine whether a module can be found *without* importing it::

```
import imp
for module in modules:
    try:
        imp.find_module(module)
    except ImportError:
        do_something()
```

Oh, and the reason you can't use `eval()` is because `import` is a statement, not an expression.  You *can* use `exec` if you *really* want to, though I wouldn't recommend it::

```
for module in modules:
    try:
        exec 'import ' + module
    except ImportError:
        do_something()
```

Answer (score 6):

What's wrong with this?

```
modules = set(["sys", "os", "jinja"])
for m in modules:
    try:
        __import__(m)
    except ImportError:
        # do something
```

The above uses the [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) function. Also, it is strictly testing whether it exists or not - its not actually saving the import anywhere, but you could easily modify it to do that.

Answer (score 5):

It's worth understanding the tradeoffs between the find_module approach and the `__import__` approach:

- `__import__('foo')` will trigger any side effects of loading the module, regardless of whether you save a reference to the imported module. That might be OK, or not.
- `find_module('foo')` won't trigger any side effects, so it should always be safe.
- neither approach works well if the module is found but has other problems at load time (eg. SyntaxError, NameError, ...)
- Depending on how you handle failures, simply wrapping `__import__('foo')` in a try/except will give you misleading results if foo is found but foo imports bar which is *not* found.
- `find_module()` can't handle dotted names, so if you need to check whether 'foo.bar.bat.baz' can be imported, you have to use multiple calls to find_module and load_module as per the [docs.](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
modules = set(["sys", "os", "jinja"])
try:
  for module in modules:
    __import__(module)
  doSomething()
except ImportError, e:
    print e
```